# LWJGL OpenGL Black Screen

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I've just started learning LWJGL/OpenGL to create a 3D game, so I started small and tried to make a simple display of a line (2D).
The window loads up fine, the right size, but nothing on the display is drawn. There is a blank screen and no changes I seem to make to the code affect what is drawn on the screen. This could be because I have a lack of understanding of how to do this correctly or it could be a problem in my code/with my computer. I've tried adding and removing various things to my initialization code such as glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) and glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D), I have tried  calling pushMatrix and popMatrix in the render code and I have tried defining the viewport in the GL11 initialization code but nothing seems to be working. My code is the following:

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.*;

public class Main {
    public Main(String[] args) throws LWJGLException{
        Logging.info("Starting up "+Info.title+" v"+Info.version+"!");
        initDisplay();
        initGL11();
        startGameLoop();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LWJGLException{
        new Main(args);
    }
    public void initDisplay(){
        try {
            Logging.info("Initializing display...");
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));
            Display.setTitle(Info.title);
            Display.create();
            Logging.info("Display initialized!");
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            Logging.severe(e);
            Display.destroy();
        }
    }
    public void initGL11() throws LWJGLException{
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0f, 800f, 600f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
    }
    public void startGameLoop(){
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
            glBegin(GL_LINE);
                glColor3f(1f,0f,0f);
                glVertex2f(0f,0f);
                glVertex2f(1f,1f);
            glEnd();

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);
        }
        Logging.info("Closing down!");
        Display.destroy();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

*Logging and Info classes are just static references to some classes that control the System.out and store static variables. These do not effect LWJGL or OpenGL so I did not see much point in including them.*

In my build path, I have **lwjgl.jar**, **lwjgl_util.jar** and **slick_util.jar** and the natives are linked to lwjgl.jar correctly. I get no errors upon starting the project and the output is normal. I am oblivious to why I am still getting a black screen. If its any use, I am following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0v56I5UWrYY&list=SP19F2453814E0E315) tutorial series to create my project and it seems to work fine in the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glOrtho(0f, 800f, 600f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
...
glVertex2f(0f,0f);
glVertex2f(1f,1f);
```

Try submitting geometry that isn't coincident with your near clipping plane.

Or adjust your near clipping plane:

```
glOrtho(0f, 800f, 600f, 0f, -1f, 1f);
```

I'd also recommend clearing the framebuffer occasionally.

Comment: I changed the geometry code to draw from points (0.1,0.1) to points (0.5,0.4) and still, I saw a black screen. I then tried changing the glOrtho code to what you suggested and that still made no difference. I also added glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT) as the first line of the inside of my while loop but the screen is still black.

Comment: @user1301590: Also, are you sure the window is *completely* blank?  Check for a red pixel in the top-left corner.  Or use `glVertex2f(800f,600f)` for your second point.

Comment: Turns out the problem was that I thought 1f covered the whole screen instead of just one pixel, everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to be calling `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)`. It should always be called before you draw.